# Using streamslice with color for velocities

Tags: matlab

I am using `streamslice` command to visualize my flow. I want to add color depending on magnitude of velocities but there seems to be no function argument in `streamslice` to do so. The function is given as:

```
 % x - x-coordinates 
 % y - y-coordinates
 % u,v - vector volume data
 h = streamslice(x,y,u,v)
```

The function produces this image [image]

Comment: You could use this quiverc() function, which will look similar to the streamslice and will give you the option to assign color based on magnitude: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3225-quiverc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `streamslice`, I can suggest something. It would need some tweaking to get it look like a cool figure, but it does the job, I guess. the idea is to combine a surf plot with the `streamsilces` plot.

Look at the result. I guess that with better a colormap and with some tricks getting the data handle of the `streamslice`to change the line colour it could work nicely, speciall yin Matlab R2014b or higher.

[image]

CODE:

```
clear;clc;
load wind
% Use only a piece of this datasheet
x=x(:,:,5);
y=y(:,:,5);
u=u(:,:,5);
v=v(:,:,5);

mag=sqrt(u.^2+v.^2);

figure
hold on
surf(x,y,mag-max(mag(:)),'FaceColor','interp','Edgecolor','none')
colormap('hot')
streamslice(x,y,u,v)
axis([min(x(:)) max(x(:)) min(y(:)) max(y(:)) -max(mag(:)) 0])
```